# Debugging XAML UnhandledException

Tags: winrt-xaml

Occasionally the UnhandledException handler in my app is raised due to an unhandled XAML exception.

The UnhandledExceptionEventArgs contains the message

> E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE

and an inner-exception of type ArgumentException

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

There is nothing in the call stack other than `InitialiseComponent()` which I can step into/ over without any exception being thrown.

Any ideas on how to debug further or any experience with `E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE` issues?

Answer (score 0):

I do remember I had to once add basically no-op value converters to some XAML so I could see what was going on and trace the error. That might help in this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to turn on mixed-mode debugging to see if more data comes from the native stack.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in UWP and it was because I was using OnIdiom

```
<OnIdiom x:Key="MyFontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="28" Phone="16">
        </OnIdiom>
```

I didn't have `desktop` included in one of the values and I was running my app on my desktop.